# Problem - 'DNS address could not be found'

Tags: macos, ios, dns

I've been trying to access the Myspace website and am receiving this message - 'www.myspace.com’s server DNS address could not be found'

I've tried using Chrome and Safari and keep getting the same result.

This is happening on my phone as well.

Answer (score 2):

From the description of your problem you encounter a generic DNS misbehaviour.

If your Mac and your iPhone are within the same network, the origin of your problem is at your network router level. Either of thrre causes may lead to this no DNS servers:
 - the DNS servers of your ISP have changed and your router configuration
   wasn't upgraded,
 - the DNS servers of your ISOP aren't reachable,
 - your router was hacked and a bad DNS server IP address was provided to
   route all your traffic toward booby trapped web servers.

To analyse further this problem, just check what is the IP address configured at your router level. You might include its complete configuration within your original question, so as to get further help.

If you see that your router configuration was changed without
your knowledge, change its default password ASAP, and
restore its correct configuration.

Answer (score -2):

Don't know if this will help but here you go: https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/6617003

It seemed to work for me now. Especially the last solution. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please don't give link-only answers.  We're looking for answers that provide explanations as to why it answers the question as well as why it's the best answer.  Links can change over time and then we'll lose the question-answer context.  See [answer] for info on what makes up a good answer.  - From Review -